# Some issue in sending email using php email function

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email from a enquiry form available on a catalogue website on which I am working and found a strange issue.

On the same domain I have a file to test the email function with following code in it:

```
$sender = 'someone@somedomain.tld';
$recipient = 'name@gmail.com';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
```

and its working fine. But the same code is not working on the `index.php` page where I have the enquiry form and also not showing any error at all (I have checked the error log. I have also tried by putting this code in a separate file and by including it on index.php but the same result).

```
<form name="frm_enquiry" id="frm_enquiry" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fullname">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile No:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="width: 100%;" for="mobile">&nbsp;</label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit'] ) )
{
    $name   = $_REQUEST['fullname'];
    $email  = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];

    echo $name . ' : ' . $email . ' : ' . $mobile . '<br>';

    $sender = 'someone@somedomain.tld';
    $recipient = 'name@gmail.com';

    $subject = "php mail test";
    $message = "php test message";
    $headers = 'From:' . $sender;

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "Message accepted";
    }
}
```

Someone please guide me, what I am doing wrong here, I am stuck on this from last 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: Check that your code is being run at all - add some echo statements at critical points.

Comment: I have tried with echo and I am getting the data from from properly

Comment: @BhaveshTailor right now I am not trying to send html email, its just a normal email that's why those headers are not there